# Is it possible to display a google map as a circle?

Tags: google-maps

I have a design I'm coding up, and on the contact page the map is meant to be a circle.  They'd like Google maps to be used.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Note: the main reason for wanting it to be a Google map is for SEO - Will it actually help rankings or is it safe to use an image?

Thank you

Comment: [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332002/how-to-insert-a-googlemap-in-a-div-with-mask)

Comment: While you worry about seo on this page I would rather recomment you to use [microformats](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146897) and embed a static map with transparent png mask or border-radius property. [Here is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484135/google-maps-api-v3-with-rounded-corner) related question with CSS solution inside.

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple.....
you can create circular div...

here is the code...

CSS:

```
#yourDivId {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      border-radius: 999px;
      -moz-border-radius: 999px;
      -khtml-border-radius: 999px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 999px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var map = new google.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("yourDivId"),mapOptions);
```

Comment: This obviously will not work in IE, which is a concern for most commercial integrations.

Comment: It will work IE9 onwards, since border-radius is a CSS3 feature.
For earlier versions you need to work out some way of showing a circular image with a transparent background and then place your map div below it.